# Why will Spring Data JDBC not work for me?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I should probably mention that Spring is my first framework that I am learning for Java.
What I am trying to do is to get the JDBC working for me using the Spring Data JDBC dependency I downloaded from spring.io. (2.6.4) I followed a tutorial on YouTube where the guy demonstrated it with something similar to the following code. (Should also mention the code he used was for Spring version 2.2 but I'm not sure where else to find right code for 2.6.4)

There is also an UnsatisfiedDependencyException I keep getting where it says:

```
Error creating bean with name 'applicationRunner' defined in com.example.demo.DemoApplication: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'applicationRunner' parameter 0;
```

I do not know why this is happening. But here is the actual code:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner applicationRunner(StudentRepo studentRepo) {
        return args -> {
            var s1 = Student.createStudent("John", "Doe");
            var s2 = Student.createStudent("Jane", "Doe");

            System.out.println(studentRepo.save(s1));
            System.out.println(studentRepo.save(s2));

            System.out.println(studentRepo.findByFName("John"));
        };
    }

}
```

CRUD Repository interface:

```
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;

public interface StudentRepo extends CrudRepository<Student, String> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE name = :name")
    List<Student> findByFName(@Param("name") String fName);
}
```

schema.sql file:

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
    id VARCHAR(50) IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName VARCHAR(50),
    lastName VARCHAR(50),
    rank VARCHAR(50)
);
```

I think it's also important for me to include pom.xml file: (Though it should also be mentioned that the pom.xml file didn't originally include the hsqldb dependency. I added that in myself.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Edit:
Exception after including `@Repository` in the CRUD repository interface:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationRunner' defined in com.example.demo.DemoApplication: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'applicationRunner' parameter 0
```

Exception after replacing `@Repository` with `@NoRepositoryBean`:

```
2022-03-23 18:30:06.531  INFO 98567 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-03-23 18:30:06.556 ERROR 98567 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

Parameter 0 of method applicationRunner in com.example.demo.DemoApplication required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.StudentRepo' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.StudentRepo' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Read the manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/2.6.3/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances

Comment: @tgdavies you linked to a really old version of the docs, and didn't really include anything helpful in your comment.

Comment: @MarkB The `@Repository` annotation is not meant for Spring Data interfaces and will have no effect on it (it will even create a WARN log entry, because it isn't meant to be there).

Comment: @Rigel In what package is the `StudentRepo` interface located?

Comment: @MarkB I updated the link. It goes to "creating repository instances"

Comment: @MarkB I tried the ```@Repository``` annotation and didn't change anything.

Comment: @dunni com.example.demo

Comment: Can you post the whole exception including stacktrace?

Comment: @dunni I was unable to due to the number of characters that were taken up but I just copied the first one I could find for the first exception.

Comment: The problem is, that the error that you posted might just be a symptom of the real root cause. So it would be interesting to see that. Maybe you can post the exception to Pastebin and add the link here.

Comment: @dunni Okay I got it here: https://pastebin.com/ZyY2mi73

Comment: @dunni I made some small change. I loaded the Maven changes for the hsqldb in the pom.xml file. Here is the new one I got: https://pastebin.com/EUm2vFaL

Comment: I posted an answer for the first exception.

Comment: This has exactly nothing to do with JDBC. It is all about dependency injection.

Comment: @user207421 I'm assuming I'm supposed to look inside the pom.xml? I can't find anything wrong there.

Comment: Please try to add `@EnableJdbcRepositories` to your application.

Answer (score 0):

try modifying the bean:

```
@Bean

public CommandLineRunner demo(StudentRepo studentRepo) {
   return (args) -> {
   studentRepo.save(new Student("Jack", "Bauer"));
   studentRepo.save(new Student("Chloe", "O'Brian"));
```

}

you can consult the guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the `schema.sql` script. An IDENTITY column in HSQLDB has to be of the type `INTEGER` or `BIGINT` (see documentation at http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/ch09.html, section `CREATE TABLE`). All other errors are just subsequent errors.

Comment: I had changed the ```@Repository``` back to ```@NoRepositoryBean``` and changed the id type to ```INTEGER``` and I got this message:
```Parameter 0 of method applicationRunner in com.example.demo.DemoApplication required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.StudentRepo' that could not be found.
```
I do not know how to define a bean of that type.

Comment: Then again look closely at the exception and the root cause (you will find the root cause at the end of the whole stacktrace).

Comment: And remove the `NoRepositoryBean` annotation. No idea why you added it. Because that annotation will prevent Spring from recognizing an interface, but you want it to be recognized as repository interface.